# document.write erase buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page with buttons:

```
 <INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="b1" onclick="init1()" >
```

init1:

```
  document.innerHTML = "<object type='application/x-app' id='plugin' width='0' height='0' > </object>"
```

When I press the button b1 it erase the page and it just blank.
What am I doing wrong?
10xs,
Nir

Comment: because you replace the html of the entire document with that object tag...

Comment: `document.write` and assigning to `document.innerHTML` are two quite different ways of manipulating the dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `appendChild` on body instead of replacing (`=`). Your button will not get erased.

```
var object = document.createElement("object");
object.innerHTML = "<object...";
document.body.appendChild(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it erases the page.  When you modify the `.innerHTML` of the -entire document-, and replace it with something else, that's what happens.

If you want to append that tag onto the document however, that's a different story.  I would suggest the following to do such:

```
var your_element = document.createElement('object');
your_element.type = 'application/x-app';
your_element.id = 'plugin'
your_element.width = 0;
your_element.height = 0;
document.body.appendChild(your_element);​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Swcbr/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to adres proper anchor (place) in your code (in the DOM tree).

Try this instead:

```
var my_anchor = document.getElementById('element_in_DOM');

my_anhor.innerHTML = "<object type='application/x-app' id='plugin' width='0' height='0' > </object>"
```